# how can i get language value randomly in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```php
class DynamicDependent extends Controller
{
    function fetch(Request $request)
    {
        $value = "home";

        $value2 = Lang::get('home.'.$value.'');
    }
}
```

> output :'home.home'.

But i need value from language file.
please guide me to get this.

Comment: Create Language Middleware. don't use this type of code. please follow this link https://medium.com/teknomuslim/multi-language-api-response-messages-in-laravel-5c9029a32e5c. You can also dynamic multi-language use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get a translation. For that you can use the `trans` helper method like this:

```
//In your resources/lang/{some_lang_code}/home.php

return [
 'home' => 'My translation',
];


//In your controller
$value = "home";
$value2 = trans('home.'.$value); //My translation
```